# Dovecot's grace_quota is not working

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mail-server, quota

My mail server is working on:

- Postfix 3.1
- Dovecot 2.2.22
- MySQL 5.7
- Ubuntu 16.04

I configured for each user's quota to be read from the mail database users table from the column `quota`:

**dovecot-sql.conf.ext**

```
driver = mysql

connect = host=127.0.0.1  dbname=mail user=admin password=XIOVwxasxvD

default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT


user_query = SELECT CONCAT('/home/vmail/',CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1))) AS home, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid, concat('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule FROM users WHERE email='%u'


password_query = SELECT email as user, password, 5000 AS userdb_uid, 5000 AS userdb_gid, concat('*:bytes=', quota) AS userdb_quota_rule FROM users WHERE email='%u';
```

And i made the following configuration to enable quota warnings on 80% and 95%, and to have a grace quota to be 10% and max 50 MB for each user,

`conf.d/90-quota.conf`:

```
plugin {
  quota_rule = *:bytes=1G
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_rule3 = Sent:storage=+100M
}

plugin {
  quota_warning = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
  quota_warning2 = storage=80%% quota-warning 80 %u
}

service quota-warning {
  executable = script /usr/local/bin/quota-warning.sh
  user = vmail
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user = vmail
  }
}

plugin {
  quota = maildir:User quota
}
plugin {
  quota_grace = 10%%
  quota_grace = 50M
}
plugin {
  quota_over_flag_value = TRUE



  quota_over_script = quota-warning mismatch %u
}
```

The warning messages are working properly, But once the user reaches the "101%" quota size it rejects any new mails with "Quota exceeded" error message to the sender without applying the grace quota configuration,

In the debug mode log I got:

```
Jul 12 18:48:57 mail postfix/smtp[23827]: 22A7FE884: to=<user@mydomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=178, delay=17, delays=0.01/16/0.01/1.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 490A8D627)
Jul 12 18:48:57 mail postfix/qmgr[25020]: 22A7FE884: removed
Jul 12 18:48:57 mail postfix/pickup[24689]: 5C653E898: uid=5000 from=<vmail@mail.mydomain.com>
Jul 12 18:48:57 mail postfix/cleanup[25288]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:9001: Cannot assign requested address
Jul 12 18:48:57 mail postfix/cleanup[25288]: 5C653E898: message-id=<20170712184857.5C653E898@mail.mydomain.com>
Jul 12 18:48:57 mail postfix/qmgr[25020]: 5C653E898: from=<vmail@mail.mydomain.com>, size=418, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail postfix/smtpd[25228]: 389E6D627: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail postfix/cleanup[25288]: 389E6D627: message-id=<20170712184840.D489CE885@mail.mydomain.com>
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail postfix/qmgr[25020]: 389E6D627: from=<vmail@mail.mydomain.com>, size=877, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota root: name=User quota backend=maildir args=
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=* bytes=1073741824 messages=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=Trash bytes=+104857600 messages=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=Sent bytes=+104857600 messages=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota warning: bytes=1020054732 (95%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 95 raw mail user
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota warning: bytes=858993459 (80%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 80 raw mail user
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: Quota grace: root=User quota bytes=52428800
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Debug: none: root=, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=, alt=
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483): Connect from local
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: USER#011104#011user@mydomain.com#011service=lmtp
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: auth-worker(15471): Debug: sql(user@mydomain.com): SELECT CONCAT('/home/vmail/',CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1))) AS home, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid, concat('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule FROM users WHERE email='user@mydomain.com'
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: auth: Debug: userdb out: USER#011104#011user@mydomain.com#011home=/home/vmail/mydomain.com/user#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011quota_rule=*:bytes=102400
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(user@mydomain.com): Debug: auth input: user@mydomain.com home=/home/vmail/mydomain.com/user uid=5000 gid=5000 quota_rule=*:bytes=102400
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(user@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_rule=*:bytes=102400
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Effective uid=5000, gid=5000, home=/home/vmail/mydomain.com/user
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota root: name=User quota backend=maildir args=
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=* bytes=102400 messages=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=Trash bytes=+104857600 messages=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=User quota mailbox=Sent bytes=+104857600 messages=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota warning: bytes=97280 (95%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 95 user@mydomain.com
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota warning: bytes=81920 (80%) messages=0 reverse=no command=quota-warning 80 user@mydomain.com
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Quota grace: root=User quota bytes=52428800
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/home/vmail/mydomain.com/user
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/home/vmail/mydomain.com/user, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/home/vmail/mydomain.com/user, alt=
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag check: STORAGE ret=1 value=101 limit=100
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag check: MESSAGE ret=0 value=99 limit=0
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag=0((null)) vs currently overquota=1
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(24483, user@mydomain.com): Debug: quota: Executing warning: quota-warning mismatch user@mydomain.com
Jul 12 18:48:58 mail dovecot: lmtp(user@mydomain.com): 4GRuG8FuZlmjXwAAPxyzFw: msgid=<20170712184840.D489CE885@mail.mydomain.com>: save failed to INBOX: Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dovecot's `grace_quota` does not work as you expect it. From the [Dovecot manual on quota](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Configuration#Quota_grace):

> With v2.2+ by default the last mail can bring user over quota. This is useful to allow user to actually unambiguously become over quota instead of fail some of the last larger mails and pass through some smaller mails. Of course the last mail shouldn't be allowed to bring the user hugely over quota, so by default in v2.2+ this limit is 10% of the user's quota limit. (In v2.1 this is disabled by default.)

With other words, `quota_grace` prevents a confusing situation where a (large) mail gets rejected because the mail exceeds the user's quota, but then newer (and smaller) mails get delivered successfully (as they still fit into the user's quota). With `quota_grace`, Dovecot allows this last, large mail to be delivered, but then blocks further mails as the user is beyond 100% quota usage.

Dovecot does not know a feature like you are looking for -- while you could simply send mails with shifted quota usage values (eg., send "you used 100% of your quota" although the user is actually still at 90% and adjust the actual limit accordingly), the actual quota is still transmitted through IMAP for mail clients that display your quota usage.

Comment: Thanks alot :), thats exactly what i was misunderstanding, i thought it would act like the scenario i mentioned,